# check if all the keys existed in the array of objects if not found add it to the array

Tags: javascript

if I have this array of objects. I am looking to add the missing keys from array of objects. For each missing key there should be three entries in the final array with name field empty.

```
myArray = [{id: 1, name: 'John'},
           {id: 1, name: 'Ray'},
           {id: 1, name: 'Elliot'},
           {id: 3, name: 'Elli'},
           {id: 3, name: 'Smith'},
           {id: 3, name: 'John'}]

my expected output should loook like:
expectedArray  = [{id: 1, name: 'John'},
                  {id: 1, name: 'Ray'},
                  {id: 1, name: 'Elliot'},
                  {id: 2, name: ''},
                  {id: 2, name: ''},
                  {id: 2, name: ''},
                  {id: 3, name: 'campbell’},
                  {id: 3, name: 'Smith'},
                  {id: 3, name: 'John'},
                  {id: 4, name: ''},
                  {id: 4, name: ''},
                  {id: 4, name: ''}]
```

I have tried different ways to acheive this task but I failed to do. Can you please help me how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: your question, sample input and output don't match. in your `expectedArray` `id:2, name: 'Campbell'` shouldn't be there, name should be blank.   Also, where didid: 3, name: 'Elli' vanish ? you might want to have a look at your sample input and output again and also provide a bit more explanation of your logic.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you mean that if all properties of a given object are not the same as an object found in the list of objects, then add it to the list.

You could do so by

```
const givenObject = {
  id: 4,
  name: ''
};

myArray.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.id !== givenObject.id || obj.name !== givenObject.name) {
    myArray.push(givenObject);
    myArray.push(givenObject);
    myArray.push(givenObject);
  }
})
```

Comment: Any of the given objects in the array should be added three times if they we were missing in the myArray

Comment: The same object should be added three times?

Comment: Edited to my answer to help you with it.